# Passing a JSON string to HTTP GET method using libcurl

Tags: json, get, query-string, libcurl, requirements

I want to pass a JSON string via the HTTP GET method. Server side requires a JSON as follows:

```
const char* json[]= {\"revisions\":[{\"revision\":\"01\"},{\"revision\":\"02\"},{\"revision\":\"03\"},{\"revision\":\"04\"}]}
```

So I intend to pass such JSON like this, but I'm not sure whether I should convert it to a query string format or not, like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com?{\"revisions\"[{\"revision\":\"01\"},{\"revision\":\"02\"},{\"revision\":\"03\"},{\"revision\":\"04\"}]}");
```

I know I should use POST in this case. However, the requirement from server side requires using GET. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean "pass it to the GET method" ? Those are all English words put in a combination that doesn't mean anything when speaking HTTP. Please elaborate on exactly how your HTTP request should look!

Comment: @DanielStenberg. Sorry to make you confused. I mean how to submit such json string (parameters) to server via GET method. I know I should add it to uri via Query string but I am not sure whether or not I need to convert it to Query string format

Answer (score 0):

Besides a query string, you can pass data in HTTP GET requests via:

- HEADER:

  ```
  struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "JSON: {\"revisions\"[{\"revision\":\"01\"},{\"revision\":\"02\"},{\"revision\":\"03\"},{\"revision\":\"04\"}]}");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
  ```
- COOKIE:

  ```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "JSON={\"revisions\"[{\"revision\":\"01\"},{\"revision\":\"02\"},{\"revision\":\"03\"},{\"revision\":\"04\"}]}");
  ```

**References**

- [CURLOPT_COOKIE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIE.html)
- [libcurl example - httpcustomheader.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html)